# What does scipy spline fit smoothing factor 's' represents in terms of balance between smoothness and robustness?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I am trying to implement a 1-D spline fit with [Scipy.univariatespline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html), but I am having some difficulties to understand what the smoothing factor s represents.

In more details, I started to read about spline fit in [this page](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/gmath/cubic_spline_fit.html), where they describe the balance between the error of the fit and the robustness of the fit with the parameter 'p' in this equation :[balance between the error of the fit and the robustness of the fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyNS3.gif)

I easily understand how tuning p between [0,1] can influence the smoothness of the spline fit. However, in scipy documentation, the smoothing factor 's' is described differently, and I have difficulties to understand it. From what I read, it is only limited by a minimum of 0. The higher it gets, the smoother the spline fit will be, and the closer to 0, the closer to the data the fit will be (Am I right?).

I tried to do a spline fit to a neuron membrane potential recording, using interpolate.UnivariateSpline and different value of s, but I don't understand its precise effect on the smoothing factor
[Spline fit for different values of 's'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk6Rg.png)

Is there a way to better map the impact of 's' to a variable that would represent the balance between smoothness and robustness like 'p'?

Thank you for any help you could give me!

Best, regards,

Julien

Comment: Perhaps this comes down to understanding knots in splines?

Comment: I understand that knots are the number of points between which a fit  will be done (right?), so the more number of knots the less smooth the fit will be, if I understood correctly. Yet in the first link I put (with p as the smoothing balance factor) knots are not mentioned directly, but the computation of the number of knots is done automatically according to p.

My question is, how can I get a sense of 's' knowing that it is theoretically not bounded by a maximum value, whereas 'p' can only go from 0 to 1, which, for me, gives a more intuitive sense of its influence on the spline fit

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517375/splines-relationship-of-knots-degree-and-degrees-of-freedom shows some simple cases, and Cross-Validated seems to have more similar questions (not necessarily Python based, but focusing on the splines).

Answer (score 0):

The smoothing factor 's' corresponds to the RSS (Residual Sum of Squares = Sum (f(x_i) - y_i)^2 ).
By setting s, you are saying that you want a RSS equal or smaller than s.
Setting s=0 means you want a perfect interpolation and so your spline will go through every point. Note that this only works if there are no repeated values for x_i (i.e. if they are strictly increasing).
By setting a high s, your spline won't need ad many knots and so your function will be smoother